# Get the openstack cinder volume size through python bindings

Tags: openstack, python-2.7

Can any one help me out to get the openstack cinder volume size through python bindings.

I have list of cinder volumes that are extracted by calling cinder_client_instance.volumes.list() method.

Now I want to know the size of the volume. How I can get the volume size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > > for volume in cinder_instance.volumes.list():
> > >       ...     print volume.id  # This will give cinder-volume ID
> > >       ...     print volume.size # This will give cinder-volume size
> > >       ...

ededdee133445454
10